# How to stop that python email get_payload returns with newLine (\r\n) for long line

Tags: python, email, get, payload

I am trying to get my google emails with Python email library.
It works fine exception one problem.

The problem is like this.
I sent an email containing long one line and run my code(get_payload()), it returns two lines with "\r\n" middle of the line seems around at 70~76th char.

```
// My code
msg = email.message_from_bytes(content[0][1])  # use this with 3
if msg.is_multipart():
  for part in msg.walk():
    print(part.get_payload(decode=True))
```

```
<1>
// Email sent
ABC DEF GHT ASDF dsf wet dg dfg et  g dg er g er g dg d g er gsdafsadwerwerewgdsgasdggas ergergdg erett asdfasddf rgergdf

// Code return
ABC DEF GHT ASDF dsf wet dg dfg et  g dg er g er g dg d g er\r\ngsdafsadwerwerewgdsgasdggas ergergdg erett asdfasddf rgergdf

<2>
// Email sent
ABC DEF GHT ASDF dsf wet dg dfg et  g dg er g er g dg d g er g sdafsad werwerew gdsgasdggas ergergdg erett asdfasddf rgergdf

// Code return
ABC DEF GHT ASDF dsf wet dg dfg et  g dg er g er g dg d g er g sdafsad\r\nwerwerew gdsgasdggas ergergdg erett asdfasddf rgergdf
```

Any body know the reason and how to stop this line feeder wrapping?
Thanks, in advance.